# If ball rebounds onto the stumps after hitting the wicket-keeper's leg, will it be a stumping?

Tags: rules, cricket

If

- the bowler has bowls the ball,
- the batsmen misses the ball,
- the ball goes to the wicket-keeper,
- it touches the leg of the keeper,
- and finally it touches the stump,

is that a stumping or not?

Comment: Was the batsman out of their ground when the bails were permanently removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the batsman was out of his crease, then yes, that is a stumping. [Law 39.2](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-39-stumped/) states:

> **39.2 Ball rebounding from wicket-keeper’s person**
>
> If the wicket is put down by the ball, it shall be regarded as having been put down by the wicket-keeper if the ball:
>
> rebounds on to the stumps from any part of the wicket-keeper’s person or equipment
>
> or      has been kicked or thrown on to the stumps by the wicket-keeper.

Note the word *any*. Since it hit his leg before going onto the stumps, it's a stumping.